# Drag and Drop: How to show "Moving" cursor while CTRL is pressed?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, mouse-cursor

I have a custom control that works like a `Canvas`. I'm trying to launch a "move" operation via `DragDrop.DoDragDrop()` (in `MouseLeftButtonDown` event handler). However, I require the user to press CTRL key during mouse down, because I have a separate use-case which the user needs to left click without pressing CTRL key.

I tried passing in only `DragDropEffects.Move` to `DoDragDrop()` but holding the CTRL key would visually show a cross ("not allowed") cursor. Using `DragDropEffects.Move | DragDropEffects.Copy` would show a cursor that looks like combination of the two operations.

Handling the `GiveFeedback` event isn't useful either - I need to set a custom cursor, or use one of the system cursors which do not include the move cursor.

How do I make it show the move cursor during drag and drop?

Comment: Could you share your code for GiveFeedback which doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This code with custom cursor loaded from resource works for me.

```
private Cursor customCursor = null;

private void Element_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.Text, <data>);
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop((DependencyObject)e.Source, data, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void Element_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Effects == DragDropEffects.Copy || e.Effects == DragDropEffects.Move)
    {
        if (customCursor == null)
        {
            var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("move.cur", UriKind.Relative));
            customCursor = new Cursor(rs.Stream);
        }

        e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
        Mouse.SetCursor(customCursor);
    }
    else
        e.UseDefaultCursors = true;
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Holding the `Ctrl` key during a drag and drop operation relates to copying the item and therefore you need to allow the DragDropEffects.Copy.